# Can you play Black Ops 3 multiplayer cross platform on Xbox One and Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, call-of-duty-black-ops, backwards-compatibility

My friend is going to get Call of Duty: Black Ops 3 but the problem is that he has a Xbox 360 and I have a Xbox One. Could we still play together on the game in multiplayer?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.

Microsoft have denied the fact that games will be made cross platform. However, the head, Phil Spencer, is now open to the idea of cross platform party chat.

Here is what Xbox Marketing Manager Harvey Eagle had to say: `"Because of the different architecture of the systems it's not possible. Your Xbox Live account on 360 will carry over to Xbox One. That same account will work on both platforms. The multiplayer won't."`

Comment: There are cross-platform games. This is mostly a developer choice.

Comment: @Eric: Keeping a decade old platform in sync sounds like a very tough task to solve.

Comment: Not at all, it all depends on what runs on the server.